# Make AlertActivity full screen in android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog

How to make `AlertActivity` full screen in android

basically `AlertActivity` is an `Activity` which `implements` `DialogInterface` [ref](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/android-4.2.2_r1/core/java/com/android/internal/app/AlertActivity.java)

Answer (score 1):

in activity oncreate() method u can write like this

```
   getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

In manifest u can write this that particular activity to set theme

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Answer (score 0):

In the manifest file inside your activity tag add this line

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your onCreateDialog() method:

```
Dialog dialog=new Dialog(this,android.R.style.Theme_Dark_NoTitleBar_FullScreen)
```

Answer (score 0):

use this on your onCreate method

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

just add this in your Menifest activity tag which you want to be full screen

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```